# Windows Monitor Display Orientation is grayed out

Tags: windows-10, display, virtual-machine, display-settings

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04 with a Windows 10 VM through Workstation Pro. I have two displays, both physically rotated to portrait mode.

The problem is that Windows 10 comes up only in landscape mode and runs well off the screen. When I go into Display Settings, Orientation is on Landscape, and the pull-down menu is grayed out. Is there a registry hack so I can make it possible to use the Windows 10 VM in portrait mode?

(Any other solution is also welcome, but I've been poking around for quite a while and cannot find one.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Update (2024):** If "Display Orientation" is grayed out, you can manually set it using the Registry. All of the monitor settings are located here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration`

I had a lot of configurations listed in mine and it was tricky to find the right one, but I was able to figure out which one it was by looking at the timestamps and picking the highest. (I think the reason I have a lot is my machine is a work machine which probably was imaged and re-imaged multiple times.) Since I have multiple monitors, I also changed the problem monitor to an uncommon resolution, and that helped me identify the correct monitor. Inside of each base key are subkeys for each monitor, which are labeled "00", "01", "02" etc. Once inside the correct monitor, go into the subkey called "00" and set "Rotation" to a value of 1-4 until you get the desired selection. After each one I unplugged the monitor and plugged it back in for the setting to take effect.

Based on my understanding of my previous answers, I believe the problem is that Windows thinks the orientation setting should be controlled by the Graphics driver, and the Graphics driver thinks the setting should be controlled by Windows. The fact that you can manually change it in the registry suggests that either of them *could* control it, and it's likely an oversight by one or both manufacturers.

**Old Answer (2017):**

I just had the same problem, though I'm using Windows 10 natively on my laptop. (No VM.) In my case the orientation drop down is disabled in the Windows Display settings, however my driver software (Intel HD Graphics) has the option on its own. From there I could change the monitor orientation and it worked great. Afterwards if I go back into the Windows Display settings I can see the monitor rotated, and the drop down is still disabled. It appears that on my setup the Windows Display orientation setting is read-only for some reason.

**Update to old answer (2019):** I just got new monitors and when I went to rotate one of them the setting was no longer available. This appears to be a limitation of the newer Intel HD Graphics Driver. My co-worker next to me has an older version of the driver and he has the settings available.